# Why would I need to synchronize NSUserDefaults if I haven't made changes?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

The documentation for `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize:]` reads:

> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals,
>   use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to **update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.**

I want to know when the part in bold might happen? I mean if there are no changes made to the user defaults, then will it be reflecting the values on disk right? Why would I have to call synchronize to update the live object? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: For more details check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183183/ios-nsuserdefaults-access-before-synchronize-completion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iOS, this can happen if the user updates something in the Settings app.

On OSX, this used to happen if your preferences were shared with another app, or if system-wide settings (say, the current language) changed. However, NSUserDefaults has been updated since then to handle this automatically, and re-read data if something has changed externally.

Note that for the latter case, the documentation is out of date. I've already filed a bug report about the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that while you are using a shared defaults object via `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, the plist file on disk gets changed due to whatever reason. Your defaults object will not recognize this change unless you are calling `synchronize` to update your shared object.

Answer (score 1):

User defaults can (could) be shared between apps. There is a global domain.