# Converting NSIndexPath to NSInteger in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, nsindexpath, nsinteger

I have a `UITableView` with a segue that connects to a view controller. When the user taps on a cell, I would like the `indexPath.row` to be passed to that view controller so I can update the content in the view based on which cell has been tapped.

I am aware of the different methods of doing this, however I would like to use `NSUserDefaults()` for my particular use. The problem is that I don't know how to convert the `indexPath.row` into an integer to be saved into `NSUserDefaults()`. This is what I have tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println(indexPath.row)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSInteger(indexPath.row), forKey: "index")

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("event", sender: self)
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("event"))
}
```

At the moment, when I try to print out the `indexPath.row` in the next view controller, it always just returns 0.

Comment: Include the code you are using to get the value back and print it.

Comment: You store the row number with the key "index", and retrieve it from the key "even" – How should that work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using the same key

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSInteger(indexPath.row), forKey: "index") // <--- INDEX

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("event")) // <-- EVENT
```

Also you :

- Might want to save it / read it with the equivalent method `setInteger:forKey:` and `integerForKey:`
- Don't have to convert the value (it's already an integer) ;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't paint yourself in a corner. An NSIndexPath contains *two* numbers, not one: A section and a row within that section. In trivial cases when a table view has only one section the section number will always be zero, but you will get more complicated cases.

If you want to store index paths, I would add a category to NSUserDefaults with one method that turns an NSIndexPath into a dictionary with keys section and row and writes that, and one that reads a dictionary and creates an NSIndexPath with the values for section and row.

That said, a row number is something horribly unstable. Your UI designers decide that two rows have to change their order, and all your preferences are broken. What I do is one enum that identifies the purpose of each row; that enum must never, ever, ever change its values, and that is stored in the preference. And then there is another enum that refers to items in the UI, and that can change freely.

Answer (score 0):

**Saving A Row(integer) Value :**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(indexPath.row, forKey: "row")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Loading A Row(integer) Value:**

```
 row() -> Int
 var row = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("row")
```

Comment: It is neither necessary nor recommended to call `synchronise()` every time a value has been set.

Comment: Refer this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183183/ios-nsuserdefaults-access-before-synchronize-completion